# search with in Data displayed as a result of tail Operation?

Tags: linux

I am working on a Java EE application where its logs will be generated inside a Linux server .

I have used the command **`tail -f -n -10000 MyLog`** 
It displayed last 1000 lines from that log file .

**Now I pressed Ctrl + c in Putty to disconnect  the logs updation  ( as i am feared  it may be  updated  with  new requests and I will loose my data )**

In the displayed result, how can I search for a particular keyword ?? (Used / String name to search but it's not working)

Comment: You should look up how to pipe the results to grep, or use grep to search through MyLog.

Answer (score 17):

Two ways:

```
tail -n 10000 MyLog| grep -i "search phrase"

tail -f -n 10000 MyLog | less
```

The 2nd method will allow you to search with /. It will only search down but you can press g to go back to the top.

**Edit:** On testing it seems method 2 doesn't work all that well... if you hit the end of the file it will freeze till you ctrl+c the tail command.

Comment: Works the first time, when I re-execute it doens't show anything.. why?

Answer (score 16):

Pipe your output to PAGER.

```
tail -f -n LINE_CNT LOG_FILE | less
```

then you can use

```
/SEARCH_STRING
```

Comment: I am able to display all the output by configuring putty settings window show scrollable lines to 1000 . After entering tail -f command and once data is displayed , i disconnect from tail option using ctrl +c , now i am not able to do this search using / String name

Comment: No. Do not kill **tail** by pressing **ctrl+c**. Run **tail -f -n LINE_CNT LOG_FILE | less**. This will kind of buffer output for you. To start with you will be in the first page. Press **h** for more info on how to use **less** PAGER. One of the feature is search which can be accomplished by hitting **/SEARCH_STRING** where **SEARCH_STRING** is the string you want to search.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the output from `tail` into a search utility (e.g. `grep`).  You could do this in two steps: save the output to a file, then search in the file; or in one go: pipe the ouput to the search utility

To see what goes into the file (so you can hit Ctlr+c) you can use the `tee` command, which duplicates the output to the screen and to a file:

```
tail -f -n -10000 MyLog | tee <filename>
```

Then search within the file.

If you want to pipe the result into the search utility, you can use the same trick as above, but use your search program instead of `tee`

Answer (score 0):

**Controlling terminal output on the fly**

While running any command in a terminal such as Putty you can use `CTRL-S` and `CTRL-Q` to stop and start output to the Putty terminal.

**Excluding lines using grep**

If you want to exclude lines that contain a specific pattern use `grep -v` the following would remove all line that contain the string INFO

```
tail -f logfile | grep -v INFO
```

Show lines that do not contain the words INFO or DEBUG

```
tail -f logfile | grep -v -E 'INFO|DEBUG'
```

Finally, the MOTHER AND FATHER of all tailing tools is [xtail.pl](http://gigo.com/ftp/pub/src/xtail.pl)

If you have perl on your host xtail.pl is a very nice tool to learn and in a nutshell you can use it to tail *multiple* files. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open it with less command

```
less logfile_name
```

when you open the file you can use this guide [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/)

**Tip**: I suggest, first to use G to go to the end of the file and then to you use Backward Search